# How do you do a chance out of 100 with a variable that can change?

Tags: java, bukkit

I was wondering if there was a way to make a chance out of 100 and for example there would be an variable out of 100 chance that something is going to happen. and i know how to make a chance normally but i'm not sure about a variable that changes. any help would be nice.
Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: like if i had a variable like 10 if i wanted to have a 10 out of 100 chance of other code executing how would i do that

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to generate random boolean value with probability to get `true` equal to some value defined by the variable?

Comment: `if (Math.random() * 100 < chance) { /* code here */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if percentage equals 1 or more you would have a 100% chance of returning true. if its 0 you have a 0% chance, so 0.5 equals a 50% chance.

```
boolean Chance(double percentage) {
    double a = Math.random();
    if(a <= percentage) {
        return true;
    }else {return false;}

}
```